# how to prove $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } {\{\Phi [(1 - \varepsilon )\sqrt {2\log n} ]\}^n}=0$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, probability-theory, normal-distribution

$\Phi (x)$ is the distribution function of standard normal distribution. $\varepsilon$ is some positive tiny number that is less than 1.

How to prove this beautiful and important limitation:
$$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } {\{\Phi [(1 - \varepsilon )\sqrt {2\log n} ]\}^n}=0$$

I've already proved $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } {\{\Phi [(1 + \varepsilon )\sqrt {2\log n} ]\}^n}=1$.
However, I met some difficulty when proving this.